# laravel model factory remove variable name from factory

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Can I remove the name from this model factory?

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

because i write unit test and create user in it and i get this error 
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
my user model is consist of firstname and lastname

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. What is the purpose? If your db model allows the name field to be null then yes, you can.

Comment: If it's nullable or has a not null default value then probably yes . Why don't you just try it and see.

Comment: @Barcelonczyk  because i write unit testing and i create user from App/user 
so when i try to run i get this error
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have "name" field in the database table. If you have "firstname" and "lastname" fields in table than you should fill them:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'firstname' => $faker->firstName,
        'lastname' => $faker->lastName,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => bcrypt(str_random(10)),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: if i dont want to add I can just delete name field ?

Comment: look when i add firstname and lastname 
it give me this error 

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'firstname' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `sls_users` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `type`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Comment: It doesn't have any sens to explain you how the framework works... I think you should read the documentation first. Your database have to be coherent with your model. So if you have "firstname" in your model you need the same field in database.